# Structure and readability of basic calculator

Tags: c, calculator

I created this code to make a basic calculator after viewing a few examples. I added the function to continue the calculations myself. I am wondering if there is a way to make this more efficient as I feel I've used some unnecessary code but I can't make it work without.

I also was looking for feedback on my codes readability and how to improve if it is of a poor quality.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
int cancel = 1;
char o, end  = 'Y';
float numone = 0.0, numtwo = 0.0;

         /* Explaining structure and receiving inputs */

         printf("Please enter the two numbers you wish to manipulate!\n");
         scanf("%f", &numone);

         do {
                 scanf("%f", &numtwo);
                 printf("Please enter the operation you wish to perform (+, -, *, /)\n");
                 scanf(" %c", &o);

                 /* Checking for correct input and manipulating numbers with regards to user input */

                 switch(o){

                         case '+':
                                 printf("%.1f + %.1f = %.1f\n", numone, numtwo, numone + numtwo);
                                 break;
                         case '-':
                                 printf("%.1f - %.1f = %.1f\n", numone, numtwo, numone - numtwo);
                                 break;
                         case '*':
                                 printf("%.1f * %.1f = %.1f\n", numone, numtwo, numone * numtwo);
                                 break;
                         case '/':
                                 printf("%.1f / %.1f = %.1f\n", numone, numtwo, numone / numtwo);
                                 break;
                         default:
                                 /* Error message for incorrect input */
                                 printf("Error! Incorrect input!\n");
                                 break;
                 }`enter code here`
                 /* Option to continue calculations */

                 printf("Would you like to perform a further calculation? (Y/N)\n");

                 /* Checking for answer and terminating if N, resuming if Y */

                 scanf(" %c%", &end);
                        if (end == 'N') {
                         return 0;
                        }
                        else {}
                 numtwo = 0;

                 /* Requesting new number to use as numtwo for calculations */

                 printf("Current number = %f please input a second number!\n", numone);
                 } while (end == 'Y');

         return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should really learn to format your code properly, for your own benefit and for the benefit of anyone else who might have to read it - it will make it much easier to understand and debug.

Comment: How do I format it properly. That's what I was wondering, to me it's readable so I don't know how to make it easier for others?

Comment: It's mainly that your indentation is all over the place and this makes the code hard to read - make the indentation consistent and logical - use 4 spaces for indent - make sure that you increase the indent level for each block and keep it the same within the block. I've re-formatted the code in your question now so that you can see the difference.

Comment: Also: enable compiler warnings and take notice of them (and fix them!).

Comment: I'm using putty and compiling produces no errors for me. What can I use to show them?

Comment: Assuming you're using gcc then you just need to specify `-Wall` when compiling, e.g. `gcc -Wall foo.c -o foo`. Try and get into the habit of always enabling warnings - it will save you a lot of grief in the long run.

Comment: @PaulR [Code in a question must not be edited.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/762/9357)  That includes whitespace, since code formatting is a valid topic for review.  The only exception is if the author obviously had trouble conveying the code as intended. I've rolled back Rev 3 → 2.

Comment: @200_success: my bad - I wasn't aware of that rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minor stuff:

I'm getting several compiler warnings. Capture the returned variable
    from `scanf()` to check if the user actually entered a number.

```
main.cpp:17: warning: ignoring return value of 'int scanf(const char*, ...)', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
         scanf("%f", &numtwo);
                             ^
```

Your `if-else` statement needs to be fixed.

```
else {
numtwo = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. **Unused Variable**

   You have an unused variable `cancel`. Remove it.

   ```
   int cancel = 1;
   ```
2. **Variable Names**

   Use variable names that shows the purpose it is doing for better readability of your code, like the char `o`. Use 'operator' instead.
3. **`scanf()` and `printf()`**

   1. Check if `scanf()` is reading correct value as @EngieOP said.

      Increase precision of the result:

      ```
      case '+':
          printf("%.2f + %.2f = %.2f\n", numone, numtwo, numone + numtwo);
          break;
      ```

      Your `scanf("c%", &end);` is giving a warning:

      > calculator.c:46:9: warning: spurious trailing ‘%’ in format [-Wformat=]
   2. Try to use `getchar()` before `scanf()` to avoid unwanted results while reading `char` using `scanf()`, or check the return value.

      ```
      printf("Would you like to perform a further calculation? (Y/N)\n");     

      /* Checking for answer and terminating if N, resuming if Y */  
      getchar();  
      scanf(" %c", &end);
      ```
4. When exiting the program check for both lower case and upper case of 'y':

   ```
   while (end == 'Y' || end == 'y');
   ```

   That also goes for 'N'.
5. There is an `else` block after

   ```
   if (end == 'N') {
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   You don't have to use an else block after each `if`. It is doing nothing. Remove it.
6. It is better to use a single return statement in `main()`. If the user presses 'N' or 'n' use break to break away from the loop.

   ```
   if (end == 'N' || end =='n') {  
       break;  
   }
   ```
7. There is no division by zero check in your code.

   ```
   case '/':    
       if(numtwo == 0){  
           printf("Can't divide by zero.\n");  
           break;  
       }

       printf("%.1f / %.1f = %.1f\n", numone, numtwo, numone / numtwo);  
       break;
   ```
8. Remove the `numtwo = 0` near the end of the `while` loop; you will read a new `numtwo` anyway.

Here is your final code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

    char operator, end  = 'Y';
    float numone = 0.0, numtwo = 0.0;

    /* Explaining structure and receiving inputs */

    printf("Please enter the two numbers you wish to manipulate!\n");
    scanf("%f", &numone);

    do {
        scanf("%f", &numtwo);
        printf("Please enter the operation you wish to perform (+, -, *, /)\n");
        scanf(" %c", &operator);

        /* Checking for correct input and manipulating numbers with regards to user input */

        switch(operator){

            case '+':
                printf("%.2f + %.2f = %.2f\n", numone, numtwo, numone + numtwo);
                break;
            case '-':
                printf("%.2f - %.2f = %.2f\n", numone, numtwo, numone - numtwo);
                break;
            case '*':
                printf("%.2f * %.2f = %.2f\n", numone, numtwo, numone * numtwo);
                break;
            case '/':
                if(numtwo == 0){  
                    printf("Can't divide by zero.\n");  
                    break;  
                }           
                printf("%.2f / %.2f = %.2f\n", numone, numtwo, numone / numtwo);  
                break;  
            default:
                /* Error message for incorrect input */
                printf("Error! Incorrect input!\n");
                break;
        }
        /* Option to continue calculations */

        printf("Would you like to perform a further calculation? (Y/N)\n");

        /* Checking for answer and terminating if N, resuming if Y */
        getchar();
        scanf(" %c", &end);
        if (end == 'N' || end =='n') {
            break;
        }           

        /* Requesting new number to use as numtwo for calculations */

        printf("Current number = %.2f please input a second number!\n", numone);
    } while (end == 'Y' || end == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Try learning about infix, postfix, prefix notations and stacks. They are easy to learn and with those you can build a far better calculator.